# react-native POST request works on Android but not IOS

Tags: ios, react-native

The API_URL is https. It works on Android.

On iPhone the request doesn't even make it to the server.
Why isn't it working on iPhone?

Here is my request:

```
export async function createGroup(
  getToken: GetToken,
  group_name: string,
  is_public = false,
): Promise<Group | string> {
  return fetch(`${API_URL}/api/groups/`, {
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${await getToken()}`,
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      Accept: 'application/json',
    },
    method: "POST",
    body: JSON.stringify({
      group_name,
      is_public,
    }),
  })
    .then((response) => {
      return response.json();
    })
    .then((json) => {
      return json.group;
    }).catch((error) => {
      return JSON.stringify(error);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the issue was the trailing slash; apparently iOS/android handle it differently! And on iOS having it there completely broke the request.

Removing the trailing slash fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Replace "your-api-domain" with your API domain, add this to your info.plist and start your project again

```xml
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <false/>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsInWebContent</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSAllowsLocalNetworking</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>your-api-domain</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSTemporaryExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSTemporaryExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
            <string>TLSv1.1</string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
```